# how to display different json data between two activities?

Tags: java, android, json

I have been trying to get my head around parsing json data in an  android app. I would like to say its going pretty well but I do have an issue. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and got it working great even hosting the file myself. However, I would like to know how to display different data between the two activities. I have narrowed it down to these two pieces of code...

This piece is from MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://jsontesthosting.x10host.com/jsontest.json";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();
            String sex = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gender))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            in.putExtra(TAG_GENDER, sex);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

This piece if from SingleContactActivity.java

public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {

```
// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
    String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
    String gender = in.getStringExtra(TAG_GENDER);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
    TextView lblGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender_label);
```

Below are the additions I have made to the layout files from the tutorial...

list_item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gender"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#acacac" />
```

activity_single_contact.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/gender_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comparing this with the tutorial you can see I have inputted the GENDER data hoping it will only display in the SingleContactActivity but it displays in both. I know its something to do with putExtra and getStringExtra. This may be a silly question but do you know how I can only get the gender information to display in the SingleContactActivity when an item in the ListView is pressed?

If you require more code please let me know and I really appreciate any help you can give me!

Edit - I have updated the code as required. I would also like to clarify what I am trying to do.

This is all testing for when I create an app I have been designing...its basically a guide. A list of characters, when one is clicked it displays that characters name and additional information about them. So in this test the json data is being parsed between two activities...but in the second activity i want there to be more information...I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn GSON.

Comment: what a comment, very helpful!!

Comment: @VM4 well I thank you for your comment but that's not very useful. I understand there is much I must learn thats why I'm here. This is just testing a small app so I can learn. So if there is anyone with a proper answer that would be great

Comment: Are you using the same layout xml file in the `SingleContactActivity` as you use for a single list item the the `MainActivity`? How are you displaying _any_ of the strings on the `SingleContactActivity`, ie- Are you calling `setText` anywhere?

Comment: @jmcdale I will update the code

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are actually doing - i get your passing data between two activities which looks fine, are you using the same list for both activities?

Comment: @jmcdale and Rob85 I have updated the code and added a clearer explanation on what I want at the bottom. Hope this helps.

Comment: this looks like all your doing is pulling some text from a list, passing it across to another activity and not doing anything else with it. Your not setting any text with the string variables you have created in the second activity.

Comment: Why do you have a `TextView` for gender in your `list_item.xml` if you don't want it to display the gender?

Comment: Also, in your `onItemClick` you should probably be using `position` to grab the necessary data from contactsList. You do not want to  call `getText` on the list item's TextViews since not all of the data is going to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem here that you are displaying information in the first list that you dont want.

SingleContactActivity is meant to display all the contact information for a single contact right?

so why in the list in the mainactivity have you put these items in. Only a list of names should be in the main activity list, you click on a name and send over the relevenat data and display it.

remove these items from the main list that are only displayed once a name is clicked on. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks I shall give this a go. I understand it may seem like a silly mistake to make but that's a beginner for you haha. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: no probs, we are all here to learn, doesnt help when you get comments like "Do your self a favour"

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer if sufficient, have a great day :-)

Comment: So i tried what you suggested...I got rid of the information I didnt need in the ListView and it does remove the information...but it also removes it from the second activity (SingleContactActivity). If you need the code updated let me know :)

Comment: ok so in the second activity you will need to repopulate a new list or not even a list just a bunch of textviews. at the moment i take it you still displaying the first list frok the main activity so obviously you will see the same info.

Comment: Actually that makes sense...will give it a go

Comment: I've been messing around with it and can't seem to get anywhere. Sorry to ask but would you be able to provide me with some code to get me started?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84695/discussion-between-rob85-and-thecreed).